# how can I send the correct database to each one

Tags: php, mysql

When I run my code it shows me each movie and the button (Details) next to each one, when i click on the details button for the first one, it shows me the correct details, but when i click on the second one, it shows me the first one also. can you please see what i should do to make each button show the correct details. thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="content-top">
                <div class="listview_1_of_3 images_1_of_3">
                    <h3>Coming Soon</h3><?php
                                        $qry3=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tbl_news order by rand() limit 2");

                                        while($n=mysqli_fetch_array($qry3))
                                        {
                                        ?>
                    <div class="content-left">
                        <div class="listimg listimg_1_of_2"><img src="admin/%3C?php%20echo%20$n['attachment'];?%3E"></div>
                        <div class="text list_1_of_2">
                            <div class="extra-wrap">
                                <button class="btn btn-success" data-target="#details-1" data-toggle="modal" type="button">Details</button>
                                <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="details-1" class="modal fade details-1" id="details-1" role="dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                <h3 class="modal-tital text-center"><span class="data" style="text-color:#000"><strong><?php echo $n['name'];?></strong></span></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <span class="data" style="text-color:#000"></span>
                                                <div class="containers-fluid">
                                                    <span class="data" style="text-color:#000"></span>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span class="data" style="text-color:#000"></span>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                            <span class="data" style="text-color:#000"></span>
                                                            <div class="center-block">
                                                                <span class="data" style="text-color:#000"><img src="admin/%3C?php%20echo%20$n['attachment'];?%3E"></span>
                                                            </div><span class="data" style="text-color:#000"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                            <span class="data" style="text-color:#000"></span>
                                                            <h4><span class="data" style="text-color:#000">Summry</span></h4><span class="data" style="text-color:#000"><span class="text-top"><?php echo $n['description'];?></span></span>
                                                            <hr>
                                                            <span class="data" style="text-color:#000"><strong>Type :<?php echo $n['type'];?></strong></span><br>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <div class="data">
                                                                Date to be published: <?php echo $n['news_date'];?>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><?php
                    }

                    ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are generating HTML elements with the same ID `id="details-1"`, which is not allowed. As pointed out in the answers, you need to generate ID dynamically or refer to the correct element in another way.

Comment: I would also suggest editing the title of this post. It's very misleading and has nothing to do with the content.

Comment: Please read about asking [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit down your question to the specific issue you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is generating exactly the same buttons
with data-target="#details-1" and corresponding DIVs id="details-1"

You need to generate them "per record".

Assuming your database records have column called "id" you can just replace that "details-1" with generated id.

```
data-target="#details-1"


data-target="#details-<?=$n['id']?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Both buttons have the same `data-target` attribute - `#details-1`. You need to assign different IDs to your buttons and their respective `div` containers in the loop:

```
$i = 0;
while($n=mysqli_fetch_array($qry3))
{
    $i++;
?>

...

<button class="btn btn-success" data-target="#details-<?php echo $i; ?>" data-toggle="modal" type="button">Details</button>
    <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="details-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="modal fade details-<?php echo $i; ?>" id="details-<?php echo $i; ?>" role="dialog">
```

This way your first movie will get ID `details-1` (and your button will point at it with the same `data-target` attribute), the second one - `details-2` and so on.